# How to create Multiple cakephp setup in single domain and using htaccess changing Url to main domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

i have a domain eg. example.com

and it contains two folder
/cakeapp1
/cakeapp2

if i use individualy then it is  working fine.
eg. http://example.com/cakeapp1 or http://example.com/cakeapp2

But i want these to point on the main domain some links are from first sub-directory and other are from second sub-directory.

**Basically i want to do the following.
If i open  http://example.com then it point to  http://example.com/cakeapp1
if i open  http://example.com/file then it point to  http://example.com/cakeapp2/file
and
if i open  http://example.com/random then it point to  http://example.com/cakeapp1/random
Please suggest me the way that how i can do the above task.**

There is problem with the htaccess also. if i use the htaccess in root and use rewrite then the both subdirectory's htaccess conflict.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In the httpd-vhosts conf file add a virtual host entry. Try below (i havent tested it but it might give you an idea)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/file
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://example.com/cakeapp2/file [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/cakeapp1$1 [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```